# How can I parallelize my loop ? (fasta file)

Tags: bash, function, loops, sed, concurrency

I wrote a script to change specific lines in one text files (fasta format) and I want to parallelize because there is a lot of lines (~800k).

```
>CTC14_37541|M00842:336:000000000-C7WWK:1:2101:20913:9309:0:66|o:97|mo:0.000000|MR:n=0;r1=0;r2=0|Q30:p=75;p=71|CO
```

And I want to transform it to:

```
>Sample-CTC14_Read37541
```

I have two problems.

1. I tried to run my script with and without function:

   - Without function, it works: all the lines I want to change are modified.
   - When I use a function, only one line is modified. Something is wrong in my function `header()`?
2. Second problem is the parallelization. I tried something with "&" but I'm not sure that is the best solution. Any idea?

My code without function and parallel:

```
#!/bin/bash

TMP_PATH="/path/where/is/my/fasta"
cd $TMP_PATH

for fasta in *.fasta
do
  echo $fasta
    lines=$(grep ">" $fasta)
    for line in $lines
  do
    if [[ $line = *">"* ]]; then
      read_nb="_Read"$(echo $line | cut -d'|' -f1 | cut -d'_' -f2)
      sample=$(echo $line | cut -d'_' -f1 | cut -d'>' -f2)
      newheader=$(echo ">Sample-$sample$read_nb")
      sed -i -e "s/$line/$newheader/g" $fasta
      sed -i -e "s/ /\n/g" $fasta
    fi
    done
done

echo "END"
```

My code with function and parallel:

```
#!/bin/bash

TMP_PATH="/path/where/is/my/fasta"
cd $TMP_PATH

n=0
maxjobs=500


header(){
    if [[ $line = *">"* ]]; then
      read_nb="_Read"$(echo $line | cut -d'|' -f1 | cut -d'_' -f2)
      sample=$(echo $line | cut -d'_' -f1 | cut -d'>' -f2)
      newheader=$(echo ">Sample-$sample$read_nb")
      sed -i -e "s/$line/$newheader/g" $fasta
      sed -i -e "s/ /\n/g" $fasta
    fi
}

for fasta in *.fasta
do
    lines=$(grep ">" $fasta)
    for line in $lines
    do
       header $line &
       #limit jobs
       if (( $(($((++n)) % $maxjobs)) == 0 )) ; then
         wait
         echo $n wait
       fi
    done
done
```

---

I have a fasta file as input that contains several headers and sequences. And I want to transform headers in order to use my fasta file in a specific workflow. I need to go from that :

```
>CTC14_18758|M00842:336:000000000-C7WWK:1:1108:17474:5670:0:66|o:98|mo:0.000000|MR:n=0;r1=0;r2=0|Q30:p=66;p=62|CO:0|
TGGGGAATATTGGACAATGGGCGAAAGCCTGATCCAGCCATGCCGCATGAGTGAAGAAGGCCTTTGGGTTGTAAAGCTCTTTTAGTGAGGAAGATAATGACGGTACTCACAGAAGAAGTCCTGGCTAACTCCGTGCCAGCAGCCGCGGTAATACGGAGAGGGCTAGCGTTATTCGGAATTATTGGGCGTAAAGGGCGCGTAGGCTGGTTAATAAGTTAAAAGTGAAATCCCGAGGCTTAACCTTGGAATTGCTTTTAAAACTATTAATCTAGAGATTGAAAGAGGATAGAGGAATTCCTGATGTAGAGGTAAAATTCGTAAATATTAGGAGGAACACCAGCGGCGAAGGCGTCTATCTGGTTCAAATCTGACGCTGAAGCGCGAAGGCTTGGGGAGCAAACAGG
>CTC14_20535|M00842:336:000000000-C7WWK:1:1108:28568:20175:0:66|o:97|mo:0.000000|MR:n=0;r1=0;r2=0|Q30:p=77;p=64|CO:0|
TGGGGAATATTGGACAATGGGCGAAAGCCTGATCCAGCCATGCCGCATGAGTGAAGAAGGCCTTTGGGTTGTAAAGCTCTTTTAGTGAGGAAGATAATGACGGTACCCACAGAAGAAGTCCTGGCTAACTCCGTGCCAGCAGCCGCGGTAATACGGAGAGGGCTAGCGTTATTCGGAATTATTGGGCGTAAAGGGCGCGTAGGCTGGTTAATAAGTTAAAAGTGAAATCCCGAGGCTTAACCTTGGAATTGCTTTTAAAACTATTAATCTAGAGATTGAAAGAGGATAGAGGAATTCCTGATGTAGAGGTAAAATTCGTAAATATTAGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGTCTATCTGGTTCAAATCTGACGCTGAAGCGCGAAGGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGG
>CTC14_24700|M00842:336:000000000-C7WWK:1:1110:7911:9824:0:66|o:97|mo:0.000000|MR:n=0;r1=0;r2=0|Q30:p=77;p=71|CO:0|
TGGGGAATATTGGACAATGGGCGAAAGCCTGATCCAGCCATGCCGCATGAGTGAAGAAGGCCTTTGGGTTGTAAAGCTCTTTTAGTGAGGAAGATAATGACGGTACTCACAGAAGAAGTCCTGGCTAACTCCGTGCCAGCAGCCGCGGTAATACGGAGAGGGCTAGCGTTATTCGGAATTATTGGGCGTAAAGGGCGCGTAGGCTGGTTAATAAGTTAAAAGTGAAATCCCGAGGCTTAACCTTGGAATTGCTTTTAAAACTATTAATCTAGAGATTGAAAGAGGATAGAGGAATTCCTGATGTAGAGGTAAAATTCGTAAATATTAGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGTCTATCTGGTTCAAATCTGACGCTGAAGCGCGAAGGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGG
```

To this:

```
>Sample-CTC14_Read18758
TGGGGAATATTGGACAATGGGCGAAAGCCTGATCCAGCCATGCCGCATGAGTGAAGAAGGCCTTTGGGTTGTAAAGCTCTTTTAGTGAGGAAGATAATGACGGTACTCACAGAAGAAGTCCTGGCTAACTCCGTGCCAGCAGCCGCGGTAATACGGAGAGGGCTAGCGTTATTCGGAATTATTGGGCGTAAAGGGCGCGTAGGCTGGTTAATAAGTTAAAAGTGAAATCCCGAGGCTTAACCTTGGAATTGCTTTTAAAACTATTAATCTAGAGATTGAAAGAGGATAGAGGAATTCCTGATGTAGAGGTAAAATTCGTAAATATTAGGAGGAACACCAGCGGCGAAGGCGTCTATCTGGTTCAAATCTGACGCTGAAGCGCGAAGGCTTGGGGAGCAAACAGG
>Sample-CTC14_Read20535
TGGGGAATATTGGACAATGGGCGAAAGCCTGATCCAGCCATGCCGCATGAGTGAAGAAGGCCTTTGGGTTGTAAAGCTCTTTTAGTGAGGAAGATAATGACGGTACCCACAGAAGAAGTCCTGGCTAACTCCGTGCCAGCAGCCGCGGTAATACGGAGAGGGCTAGCGTTATTCGGAATTATTGGGCGTAAAGGGCGCGTAGGCTGGTTAATAAGTTAAAAGTGAAATCCCGAGGCTTAACCTTGGAATTGCTTTTAAAACTATTAATCTAGAGATTGAAAGAGGATAGAGGAATTCCTGATGTAGAGGTAAAATTCGTAAATATTAGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGTCTATCTGGTTCAAATCTGACGCTGAAGCGCGAAGGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGG
>Sample-CTC14_Read24700
TGGGGAATATTGGACAATGGGCGAAAGCCTGATCCAGCCATGCCGCATGAGTGAAGAAGGCCTTTGGGTTGTAAAGCTCTTTTAGTGAGGAAGATAATGACGGTACTCACAGAAGAAGTCCTGGCTAACTCCGTGCCAGCAGCCGCGGTAATACGGAGAGGGCTAGCGTTATTCGGAATTATTGGGCGTAAAGGGCGCGTAGGCTGGTTAATAAGTTAAAAGTGAAATCCCGAGGCTTAACCTTGGAATTGCTTTTAAAACTATTAATCTAGAGATTGAAAGAGGATAGAGGAATTCCTGATGTAGAGGTAAAATTCGTAAATATTAGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGTCTATCTGGTTCAAATCTGACGCTGAAGCGCGAAGGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGG
```

And I want to make this parallel because I have a lot of lines to change (~700-800k) and it takes very long time if I run the script line by line.

With my script without function, job is works but it's too long.

With my script with function and parallel, job doesn't work fine because only one header is changed in my fasta instead of all headers and I don't understand why. I tried different ways to write and call my function but the result is always the same.

Moreover, I tried with the gnu-parallel but it's the same way. I think my function or my call have a problem but I don't understand where.

I think use awk as you suggested is a good idea but I'm not comfortable with it. Can you help me please?

---

Proper format of my fasta file is:

```
>CTC14_1600|M00842:336:000000000-C7WWK:1:1101:26089:18004:0:66|o:97|mo:0.000000|MR:n=0;r1=0;r2=0|Q30:p=77;p=71|CO:0| TGGGGAATATTGGACAATGGGCGAAAGCCTGATCCAGCCATGCCGCATGAGTGAAGAAGGCCTTTGGGTTGTAAAGCTCTTTTAGTGAGGAAGATAATGACGGTACTCACAGAAGAAGTCCTGGCTAACTCCGTGCCAGCAGCCGCGGTAATACGGAGAGGGCTAGCGTTATTCGGAATTATTGGGCGTAAAGGGCGCGTAGGCTGGTTAATAAGTTAAAAGTGAAATCCCGAGGCTTAACCTTGGAATTGCTTTTAAAACTATTAATCTAGAGATTGAAAGAGGATAGAGGAATTCCTGACGTAGAGGTAAAATTCGTAAATATTAGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGTCTATCTGGTTCAAATCTGACGCTGAAGCGCGAAGGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGG$
>CTC14_11169|M00842:336:000000000-C7WWK:1:1105:11636:11876:0:66|o:97|mo:0.000000|MR:n=0;r1=0;r2=0|Q30:p=76;p=65|CO:0| TGGGGAATATTGGACAATGGGCGAAAGCCTGATCCAGCCATGCCGCATGAGTGAAGAAGGCCTTTGGGTTGTAAAGCTCTTTTAGTGAGGAAGATAATGACGGTACTCACAGAAGAAGTCCTGGCTAACTCCGTGCCAGCAGCCGCGGTAATACGGAGAGGGCTAGCGTTATTCGGAATTATTGGGCGTAAAGGGCGCGTAGGCTGGTTAATAAGTTAAAAGTGAAATCCCGAGGCTTAACCTTGGAATTGCTTTTAAAACTATTAATCTAGAGATTGAAAGAGGATAGAGGAATTCCTGATGTAGAGGTAAAATTCGTAAATATTAGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGTCTATCTGGTTCAAATCTGACGCTGAAGCGCGAAGGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGG$
>CTC14_16471|M00842:336:000000000-C7WWK:1:1107:6941:10486:0:66|o:97|mo:0.000000|MR:n=0;r1=0;r2=0|Q30:p=77;p=70|CO:0| TGGGGAATATTGGACAATGGGCGAAAGCCTGATCCAGCCATGCCGCATGAGTGAAGAAGGCCTTTGGGTTGTAAAGCTCTTTTAGTGAGGAAGATAATGGCGGTACTCACAGAAGAAGTCCTGGCTAACTCCGTGCCAGCAGCCGCGGTAATACGGAGAGGGCTAGCGTTATTCGGAATTATTGGGCGTAAAGGGCGCGTAGGCTGGTTAATAAGTTAAAAGTGAAATCCCGAGGCTTAACCTTGGAATTGCTTTTAAAGCTATTAATCTAGAGATTGAAAGAGGATAGAGGAATTCCTGATGTAGAGGTAAAATTCGTGAATATTAGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGTCTATCTGGTTCAAATCTGACGCTGAAGCGCGAAGGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGG$
```

Comment: you wrote *Something is wrong in my function "header{}"?* . Did you mean `header()`? If so please edit your Q. What you have looks reasonable, and to solve the problem of *when I use a function, only one line is modified* you'll learn more by taking apart your function line by line, executing each section and then adding the next section (after a `|` char), see that that is changing the output as expected, and continue until you find the source of your problem. We really can't help without sample input and expected output. BUT I would recommend rewriting all of that text processing in `awk` ..

Comment: ... only one process, it will be much more efficient. You may not need to parallelize. And your parrallelization using `&` should make things run faster. But we don't know what is in the code you call after, i.e. `limit jobs` (althought that sounds good). while `wait` (with the `$maxjobs` check) seems very likely to work. You might want to see if you have/or get installed `gnu-parallel` as that is a tool designed for large scale processing. Good luck.

Comment: Hi shellter and thanks for your answer. I edited my issue to answer you and better explain my problem...

Comment: Too much information (I think). You want to change `>Sample-CTC14_Read18758 `  to `>Sample-CTC14_Read18758`? AND you want to remove the 2ndary header, i.e. `C7WWK:1:1110:7911:9824:0:66|o:97|mo:0.000000|MR:n=0;r1=0;r2=0|Q30:p=77;p=71|CO:0| ` ? `sed can do all of that in one call. See below.

Comment: Please confirm that (for your first sample record), `>CTC14_18758|M00842:336:000000000-` is on a separate line from what follows i.e. `C7WWK:1:1108:28568:20175:0:66|o:97|mo....`. Tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `>CTC14_18758|M00842:336:000000000-` is on a separate line, this code will convert the input to the output.

```
#!/bin/sed -f

#skip blank lines
/^[[:space:]]*$/n

#change >CTC14_18758|M00842:336:000000000-
#  to >Sample-CTC14_Read18758
s/^>/>Sample-/
s/_/_Read/
/^>/s/|.*$//

# remove 2ndary header
#  C7WWK:1:1108:17474:5670:0:66|o:98|mo:0.000000|MR:n=0;r1=0;r2=0|Q30:p=66;p=62|CO:0| TGGGGAATATTGGAC...
# to
#  TGGGGAATATTGGAC...

s/^[^>].*| //
```

Save that as a file/script.
Then mark it as executable with

```
chmod +x mySed
```

and run it like

```
./mySed -i fileIn
```

Or if you get an warning/error message about `-i`, then run

./mySed fileIn > fileOut && mv fileOut fileIn

Now you can eliminate your function `header()`, and the 2ndary loop in your code. 
Just

```
for file in *.fasta ; do
   echo "processing file=$file"
   /path/to/mySed -i "$file"
   # run other processing if needed
   # don't think you need wait any more
   #uncomment? wait
done
```

## -------------- version 2 sed ---------------

```
#!/bin/sed -f

#skip blank lines
/^[[:space:]]*$/n

#>CTC14_18758|M00842:336:000000000-C7WWK:1:1108:17474:5670:0:66|o:98|mo:0.000000|MR:n=0;r1=0;r2=0|Q30:p=66;p=62|CO:0| TGGGGA...

#change >CTC14_18758|M00842:336:000000000-
#  to >Sample-CTC14_Read18758
s/^>/>Sample-/
s/_/_Read/
s/|.*| / /
# /^>/s/-.*| / /
# s/-.*| / /
```

works with data like

```
>CTC14_16471|M00842:336:000000000-C7WWK:1:1107:6941:10486:0:66|o:97|mo:0.000000|MR:n=0;r1=0;r2=0|Q30:p=77;p=70|CO:0| TGGGGAATATTGGACAATGGGCGAAAGCCTGATCCAGCCATGCCGCATGAGTGAAGAAGGCCTTTGGGTTGTAAAGCTCTTTTAGTGAGGAAGATAATGGCGGTACTCACAGAAGAAGTCCTGGCTAACTCCGTGCCAGCAGCCGCGGTAATACGGAGAGGGCTAGCGTTATTCGGAATTATTGGGCGTAAAGGGCGCGTAGGCTGGTTAATAAGTTAAAAGTGAAATCCCGAGGCTTAACCTTGGAATTGCTTTTAAAGCTATTAATCTAGAGATTGAAAGAGGATAGAGGAATTCCTGATGTAGAGGTAAAATTCGTGAATATTAGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGTCTATCTGGTTCAAATCTGACGCTGAAGCGCGAAGGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGG
```

IHTH